# Where will I find the source code for Google App Engine Flexible environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I want to download the source code in my Python 3 App Engine flexible environment. I see how you can SSH in, or go in from the terminal, to look at source code. But I don't want to turn debug on a production machine. Instead, is it possible to just list the files, and then download to my machine?

The app was uploaded using Docker, pushed to gcr.io, and deployed with `gcloud app deploy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to copy the source code from the App Engine Flex environment by following these steps:

1. Fetch the App Engine image to be used by performing either the following:

   - Navigate to [Google Container Registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr) then select `appengine`
   - Typing `gcloud container images list --repository [region]/[project-name]/appengine` in Cloud Shell

   Supported regions:

   - `gcr.io`
   - `us.gcr.io`
   - `eu.gcr.io`
   - `asia.gcr.io`
2. Create a container using Docker:

   `docker create --name=gae-source [region]/[project-name]/appengine/[service].[version]:[tag]`

   It would be easier to copy the full repository name then add the `tags` afterwards by clicking the copy [image: 2] button beside the repository name or `service.version`.
3. Copy the files from the docker container:

   `docker cp gae-source:/app . --follow-link`
4. Check if the files are successfully copied:

   `ls ./app`
5. Compress the files by performing:

   `tar -czvf app.tar.gz ./[folder]`
6. You may now download the compressed file on your local machine.

I managed to view the source code by using the Cloud Shell Editor. I didn't have to download the files.

You can check this [Github link](https://github.com/bhidalto/gae-source#google-container-repository-image) that I followed.

Comment: Thanks Robert G. That's just what I needed. I could find the correct container in the console and then do everything from the terminal and never had to turn on debuggin.